# React Native 0.64.0 doesn't update bundle in ios

Tags: typescript, react-native

Could you please help me with React Native?
I'm stuck after the update to RN 0.64.0
Actually, everything works, except the hot reload feature.

RN just don't see changes, Metro bundler successfully starts but has no connections to the server.
It looks like my simulator starts in production mode, although as I can see from CLI it's a debug mode:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme App -destination id=F824C7B1-2D0C-482C-AF5B-6DA74F4DD997
```

And now I have to bundle my app each time when I want to see the changes.

The scheme in IOS is set to "debug".
I run

```
npx react-native-clean-project clean-project-auto
```

And cleaned everything but still, it hasn't helped yet.

Help me please if it's possible.
Thanks. guys!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded today and I'm not facing your issue. I recommend that you go over you upgrade steps file by file using https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.4&to=0.64.0